# Fantasy book series from the 80s

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I'm trying to remember this book, I'm pretty sure it was from a series.

The main character was a male, possibly middle aged, I think at the beginning of the book, he's decided to retire and become a "man of leisure" but he soon finds out that full time leisure is boring.

Somehow he gets involved in an adventure or quest of some kind.

For some reason I think of him as a sort of hobbit-like character but I'm not sure if he was human or some other race. Also, he referred to himself in the third person.

The only other thing I remember is something about blocks or wheels of cheese, maybe just a scene involving this.

I think it was YA humorous sort of fantasy. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Do you recall if there was any kind of magic involved?

Comment: It's a fairly generic plot type. Can you give any more details about it? Did the man move from our contemporary world into another? Did he decide to retire or was he looking for an escape from something? It does sounds a little like [Magic Kingdom for Sale - Sold!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Kingdom_for_Sale%E2%80%93Sold!) by Terry Brooks, but could be one of many others of a similar type too.